# Pass parameter from C/C++ JNI to Java and get modified value

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

**Short Question:**

Passing a parameter from C++/C JNI to Java method who supposed to modify. Will the modified result available back in C/C++ JNI? Is there any way to do it? Other than return and a callback from java?

**Continue if above is not clear:**

Calling below function from C/C++ JNI with jcharArray. Below Java function is supposed to work on passed char array and store the final result in same. So that modified result will be available back in C/C++ JNI.

I have java function accepting a char[] like below

```
void GetName(char[] s)
{
    String t = "Test";
    // Work on t and store the result in s
    s = t.toCharArray();
}
```

How I can achieve this ... I am getting all the examples that are another way around like Java calling C/C++.

Comment: *Hint* Does `void GetName(char[] s) { s[0] = 'T'; s[1] = 'e'; s[2] = 's'; s[3] = 't';}` work ?

Comment: I got a problem with this.  You can't pass by reference in the C language.  The C language passes by value or you can pass a pointer.  In C++, you can pass by value, reference or pointer.  Please update language tags accordingly.  Also, edit your post because there is no language "C/C++".

Comment: This is what GetName does: takes a value for s, discards it by assigning s a new value and then discards that by returning. It has no effect. A really good compiler/static analysis tool might tell you these things. (General practice: don't replace values in parameter variables [except for minor tweaks to prep for algorithms].) See the answer for ways to do what you need.

Answer (score 6):

Java only supports pass by value. If you want to return a reference you need to either

a) return it

```
char[] getName();
```

b) Pass a mutable object to reference it

```
void getName(char[][] nameArray) {
    nameArray[0] = t.toCharArray();
}
```

c) Pass a call back

```
void getName(Consumer<char[]> listener) {
    listener.accept(t.toCharArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So for my scenario, I modified the declaration like below

```
void GetName(char[] s) to void GetName(PersonName obj)
```

So now, I am creating an object of PersonName in JNI and passing that as a parameter to the java function. Later I am using the same object to call getter methods of the PersonName class to get the values char[] RetriveName();

I also found that using jfield also you can get the values of the class data members but then those members should be public